# Downloading worldclim

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff

https://www.worldclim.org/data/monthlywth.html

On this page, I want to download data.

1st issue, when I click on a link, for example tmin_1990-1999, nothing happens.

I solved this using a piece of R code.

```
url <- "http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.1/fut/2.5m/wc2.1_2.5m_tmin_CanESM5_ssp126_2041-2060.zip"
destfile <- "D:/wc2.1_2.5m_tmin_CanESM5_ssp126_2041-2060.zip" 
download.file(url, destfile)
```

Comment: Links work for me. Click, slight pause, then a download starts. Does your browser have any ad-blockers or other things that might block it?

Comment: no ad blockers, no... do you get 120 files ?

Comment: Its a 3.6Gb download which is a bit much on my connection right now. How did you get the file with your R code? Maybe that code is only getting 12 files. Have you got just one year? Please show your R code.

Comment: ```url <- "http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.1/fut/2.5m/wc2.1_2.5m_tmin_CanESM5_ssp126_2041-2060.zip"
destfile <- "D:/wc2.1_2.5m_tmin_CanESM5_ssp126_2041-2060.zip"
download.file(url, destfile)```

Comment: strangley, it works with microsoft edge. I was using Google chrome. So, the problem is "solved", but I would be curious to understand...

Comment: That URL is not the same ZIP files that you gave the address for in the question. The future data, which you give the URL for in the comment above, is averaged monthly values over the 20 year period 2041-2060, and is only one file (not 12) in the zip. The file has 12 raster *layers* though.  I was using firefox but can try chrome later. its possibly an ad blocker or tracker blocker or some security feature of chrome blocking it... Possibly because these are *http* links on an *https* (secure) web page...

Comment: Yes I know it was not the same link, just to show the R functions I used, as you asked for the code ;)

Comment: I've investigated with chrome and now I understand the problem and have reported it to worldclim. I've also deleted your second question since we like one Q = one A here. If you still have a problem with the expected number of files in a zip downloaded from worldclim please add a new question including the code you used to get the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I try and access the http:// based files from the https:// worldclim site it works in Firefox and Chrome, but the Chrome console shows this message:

Mixed Content: The site at 'https://www.worldclim.org/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'https://data.biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.1/hist/wc2.1_2.5m_tmax_1960-1969.zip' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download will be blocked in future versions of Chrome. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.

and I suspect you are using a newer Chrome which has blocked this.

I've emailed the worldclim team with a full report.

UPDATE: The worldclim admin replied and have updated the page so that the files now have https:// links and should work in all browsers.